# Regular Expressions Match Specific Location In File

Tags: regex, solaris, grep

The file i am working with (oraInst.loc) looks like this:

```
inventory_loc=/u01/app/ORAENV/oracle/oraInventory
inst_group=dba
```

I need to use a regular expression to grab the value between app/ and /oracle. In this case it will be ORAENV but it could be any alphanumeric string of any case and length but with no spaces.

From what I have read so far using grouping seems to be the way to do this but I just can't get my head round it.

I am using egrep on Solaris 10 as the regex engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, assuming your egrep has -o:

```
$ echo '/u01/app/ORAENV/oracle/oraInventory' | egrep -o '/app/[0-9A-Za-z]+/oracle/' | cut -d'/' -f3
```

Output:

```
ORAENV
```

Update, solution using sed:

```
$ echo '/u01/app/ORAENV/oracle/oraInventory' | sed 's:.*/app/\(.*\)/oracle/.*:\1:'
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion unfortunately my egrep does not support "-o". Gotta love solaris standard tools... the bane of my life lately.

Comment: Perhaps grep is not the right tool for you. How about sed instead?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

> `\/app\/([\d\w]+)\/oracle\/`

Comment: bash-3.00# egrep /app/([\d\w]+)/ /var/opt/oracle/oraInst.loc
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Is this a problem with egrep?

Comment: bash-3.00# egrep \/app\/([\d\w]+)\/oracle\/ /var/opt/oracle/oraInst.loc

bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Maybe I am not using egrep correctly

Comment: since you are using bash, you'll have to escape all special characters: for example, replace \d with \\d

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
app/(.*)/oracle
```

Would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo "inventory_loc=/u01/app/ORAENV/oracle/oraInventory"| nawk -F"/" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i=="app") {print $(i+1);exit} } '
ORAENV
```